# Prime elements in the ring of integers.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, prime-numbers

Let $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{{1+\sqrt{-3}}}{2}]$ be the ring of integers where $\alpha=\frac{{1+\sqrt{-3}}}{2}$. I wish to show that $1-\alpha$ is a prime and check whether 3 is a prime or not.

To show that $1-\alpha$ is prime, suppose $1-\alpha$ divides $(a+b\alpha)(c+d\alpha)$. Then I wish to show that it divides one of them. I wrote down the division algorithm for $1-\alpha$ divides $(a+b\alpha)(c+d\alpha)$ but it's a big mess that I can't seem to make sense of. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Think about norms.

Comment: I know how to use norm to show that an element is irreducible or a unit. But I'm not sure how to go about showing an element is prime. I found that the norm of $1-\alpha$ is 1. Shouldn't it be a unit instead of prime then?